# Play 2 / Scala - Generic Reactive Mongo CRUD - json serialization

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, crud, reactivemongo

I`ve found some questions that are very close to my question (e.g. [Play Framework / Scala: abstract repository and Json de/serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566833/play-framework-scala-abstract-repository-and-json-de-serialization)) but they didnt solve my problem.

What I`m trying to achieve is an abstraction of my CRUD DAO for the common crud operations.

I build a GenericMongoDaoActor for that:

```
abstract class GenericMongoDaoActor[T <: Entity: Writes](implicit inj:Injector, implicit val f:Format[T]) extends Actor with Injectable {
  protected val db = inject[DefaultDB]
  protected val collectionName: String
  protected val collection:JSONCollection

  //set to None to use fallback
  def defaultSelector(obj:T):Option[JsObject] = None
  def fallbackSelector(obj:T) = Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$elemMatch" -> obj._id))

  protected def find(jsObject: JsObject) = {
    val currentSender = sender
    val futureOption = collection
      .find(jsObject)
      .cursor[T](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred)
      .headOption

    futureOption.mapTo[Option[T]].flatMap {
      case Some(pobj) =>
        currentSender ! Some(pobj)
        Future{pobj}
      case None =>
        currentSender ! None
        Future{None}
    }
  }

  protected def save(obj:T):Unit = {
    update(obj, true)
  }

  protected def update(obj:T):Unit = {
    update(obj, false)
  }

  private def update(obj:T, upsert: Boolean):Unit = {
    val selector = defaultSelector(obj) match {
      case None => fallbackSelector(obj)
      case Some(sel) => sel
    }
    collection.update(
      selector,
      obj,
      GetLastError.Default,
      upsert).onComplete {
      case Failure(e) => Logger.error("[" + this.getClass.getName + "] Couldn`t update " + obj.getClass.getName + ": " + Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(obj)), e)
      case Success(lastError) => //currentSender ! lastError todo: do something with lastError
    }
  }

  def findAll() = {
    collection.find(Json.obj()).cursor[T](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect[List]()
  }

}
```

The DAOActor handles Entities that inherit abstract class "Entity":

```
abstract class Entity {
  val _id: BSONObjectID
}
```

Currently there are 2 classes that inherit Entity..

As you can see my DOAActor is already context bound to look for Writes[T] in scope..

```
abstract class GenericMongoDaoActor[T <: Entity: Writes]
```

When I try to build my project like that, it complains that there are no OWrites given to serialize "obj" of type "T" in the update method.

```
No Json serializer as JsObject found for type T. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type.

collection.update( <-------------
```

I couldnt find a way to solve this issue. Please let me know if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems when I migrated from an earlier version of ReactiveMongo. What worked for me was sprinkling around some `.as[JsObject]` conversions in the various calls to the ReactiveMongo API.

So if before I had:

```
 collection.update(
  selector,
  obj,
  ...
)
```

I replaced it with:

```
collection.update(
  selector,
  obj.as[JsObject],
  ...
)
```

This seemed to be sufficient, although I *am* supplying the necessary JSON converter(s) in a slightly different way to you; subclasses of my abstract class have to implement an `implicit val fmt:Format[T]` member. I doubt whether that is important, but it is an approach that seems to be working :-)

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I still dont get why it complains that it needs owrites or oformat on top..

Answer (score -1):

You need to use OWrites and OFormat instead of Writes and Format.
I know OWrites extends Writes and OFormat extends Format, but the reactivemongo version you are using is waiting for OWrites and OFormat, not its super types.

Comment: That's not possible to use `Writes` instead of `OWrites`, as the specificity of writing a structure corresponding to expected BSON document has to be enforce with `JsObject`, not `JsValue` (result of `Writes`).

Comment: @cchantep I said "use OWrites instead of Writes". The use of .as[JsObject] is a hack, not a solution. The newest versions of play-reactivemongo use OWrites, OFormat, etc. I had the same error. Please, read the error.